# Error Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority com.example.fileprovider

Tags: java, android

me aparece un error al momento de capturar una foto comparto contenido de mis archivos
ya modifique en esta parte del codigo por la f mayuscula como aparece en androidManifest pero no me funciona, agradeceria mucho de su apoyo para encontrar el error, Gracias.

Error

```
Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority com.example.xxx.provider
```

comparto contenido de mis archivos:

AndroidManifest:

```
 <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.root.colectapp.FileProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
        </provider>
```

file_paths:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-files-path
    name="mis_imagenes"
    path="."></external-files-path>
</paths>
```

me apunta a la siguiente linea de codigo (ya modifique la F mayuscula como esta en androidManifest)

`````
 Uri fotoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.example.root.colectapp.fileprovider", imagenArchivo);
````
`````

Answer (score 1):

Primeramente, no es permitido actualmente por motivos de seguridad usar "." para referenciar la ruta de los archivos externos.

```
<external-files-path
    name="mis_imagenes"
    path="."></external-files-path>
```

---

Para solucionar este problema, debes definir tu ruta dentro del directorio `/files`:

```
 <external-files-path
        name="mis_imagenes"
        path="files/"></external-files-path>
```

y define tu `provider` dentro del archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` de esta forma haciendo referencia al directorio `/files`:

```
 <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.root.colectapp.FileProvider/files/"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
        </provider>
```

Comment: Hola Gracias por la ayuda, pero no se ha corregido mi problema :( me marca este mismo error